# How to format axis tick labels from number to thousands or Millions (125,436 to 125.4K)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks, yticks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style="darkgrid")    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))    
palette = sns.color_palette("bright", 6)
g = sns.scatterplot(ax=ax, x="Area", y="Rent/Sqft", hue="Region", marker='o', data=df, s=100, palette= palette)
g.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), ncol=1)
g.set(xlim = (50000,250000))
```

[image]

How can I can change the axis format from a number to custom format? For example, 125000 to 125.00K

Answer (score 56, accepted):

IIUC you can format the xticks and set these:

```
In[60]:
#generate some psuedo data
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[50000, 75000, 100000, 125000], 'Rent/Sqft':np.random.randn(4), 'Region':list('abcd')})
df

Out[60]: 
      num  Rent/Sqft Region
0   50000   0.109196      a
1   75000   0.566553      b
2  100000  -0.274064      c
3  125000  -0.636492      d

In[61]:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style="darkgrid")    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))    
palette = sns.color_palette("bright", 4)
g = sns.scatterplot(ax=ax, x="num", y="Rent/Sqft", hue="Region", marker='o', data=df, s=100, palette= palette)
g.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), ncol=1)
g.set(xlim = (50000,250000))
xlabels = ['{:,.2f}'.format(x) + 'K' for x in g.get_xticks()/1000]
g.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

Out[61]:
```

[image]

The key bit here is this line:

```
xlabels = ['{:,.2f}'.format(x) + 'K' for x in g.get_xticks()/1000]
g.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
```

So this divides all the ticks by `1000` and then formats them and sets the xtick labels

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @ScottBoston who has suggested a better method:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.2f}'.format(x/1000) + 'K'))
```

see the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_major_formatter.html)

Comment: You can also, try using ticker.FuncFormatter:  `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.2f}'.format(x/1000) + 'K'))`

Comment: Note that the `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` approach doesn't work if you your figure is a `FacetGrid`.

Answer (score 40):

The canonical way of formatting the tick labels in the standard units is to use an [`EngFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter). There is also [an example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/engineering_formatter.html) in the matplotlib docs.

Also see [Tick locating and formatting](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html)

Here it might look as follows.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"xaxs" : np.random.randint(50000,250000, size=20),
                   "yaxs" : np.random.randint(7,15, size=20),
                   "col"  : np.random.choice(list("ABC"), size=20)})
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))    
palette = sns.color_palette("bright", 6)
sns.scatterplot(ax=ax, x="xaxs", y="yaxs", hue="col", data=df, 
                marker='o', s=100, palette="magma")
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), ncol=1)
ax.set(xlim = (50000,250000))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: for anyone running this code with `matplotlib 3.3.1` and `seaborn 0.10.1`, you'll get `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`. To resolve that issue, change `hue='col'` to `hue=df.col.tolist()`. This is a known bug.

Answer (score 10):

Using **Seaborn** *without* importing *matplotlib*:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

chart = sns.relplot(x="x_val", y="y_val", kind="line", data=my_data)

ticks = chart.axes[0][0].get_xticks()

xlabels = ['$' + '{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ticks]

chart.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
chart.fig
```

Thank you to EdChum's answer above for getting me 90% there.

Comment: If you want to use formatters (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) and not import matplotlib, you can use: `chart.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`

Answer (score 6):

**Here's how I'm solving this:** (similar to ScottBoston)

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

f = lambda x, pos: f'{x/10**3:,.0f}K'
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(f))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could used the APIs: `ax.get_xticklabels()` , `get_text()` and `ax.set_xticklabels` do it.

e.g,

```
xlabels = ['{:.2f}k'.format(float(x.get_text().replace('−', '-')))/1000 for x in g.get_xticklabels()]
g.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please [include an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364) of how and why this solves the problem. This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30166897)