# How to format the y- or x-axis labels in a seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I want to format y-axis labels in a seaborn FacetGrid plot, with a number of decimals, and/or with some text added.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="ticks")

exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)
#g.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.2f}'.format(x) + 'K'))
#g.set(xticks=['a','try',0.5])
g.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.2f}'.format(x) + 'K'))
plt.show()
```

Inspired from [How to format seaborn/matplotlib axis tick labels from number to thousands or Millions? (125,436 to 125.4K)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747298/how-to-format-seaborn-matplotlib-axis-tick-labels-from-number-to-thousands-or-mi)

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.2f}'.format(x) + 'K'))
```

It results in the following error.

`AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'xaxis'`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `xaxis` and `yaxis` are attributes of the plot `axes`, for a `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid` type.

  - In the linked answer, the type is `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`
- `p` in the `lambda` expression is the tick label number.
- [seaborn: Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)
- [matplotlib: Creating multiple subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)
- Tested and working with the following versions:

  - `matplotlib v3.3.4`
  - `seaborn v0.11.1`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr

sns.set(style="ticks")

# load data
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# plot data
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)

# format the labels with f-strings
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: f'{y:.2f}: Oh baby, baby'))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: f'{x}: Is that your best'))
```

[image]

- As noted in a comment by [Patrick FitzGerald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14148248/patrick-fitzgerald), the following code, without using `tkr.FuncFormatter`, also works to generate the previous plot.
- See [`matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_formatter.html)

```py
# format the labels with f-strings
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda y, p: f'{y:.2f}: Oh baby, baby')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, p: f'{x}: Is that your best')
```