# How to customize the text ticklabels for each subplot of a seaborn catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid, catplot

Let us consider the following example (from Seaborn [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)):

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

fg = sns.catplot(x="age", y="embark_town",
                hue="sex", row="class",
                data=titanic[titanic.embark_town.notnull()],
                orient="h", height=2, aspect=3, palette="Set3",
                kind="violin", dodge=True, cut=0, bw=.2)
```

Output:

[image]

I want to change the tick labels on the y axis, for example by prepending a number in parenthesis: (1) Southampton, (2) Cherbourg, (3) Queenstown. I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711652/162684), and I have tried to use a `FuncFormatter`, but I obtain a strange result. Here is my code:

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

fg = sns.catplot(x="age", y="embark_town",
                hue="sex", row="class",
                data=titanic[titanic.embark_town.notnull()],
                orient="h", height=2, aspect=3, palette="Set3",
                kind="violin", dodge=True, cut=0, bw=.2)

from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
for ax in fg.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'({1 + pos}) {x}'))
```

And here is the output:

[image]

It looks like `x` is the same as `pos` in the `lambda`. I was expecting `x` to be the value of the tick label (i.e. Southampton, Cherbourg, Queenstown). What am I doing wrong?

---

Software versions:

```
matplotlib                         3.4.3
seaborn                            0.11.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Similar to the answers for [How to rotate xticklabels in a seaborn catplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63909351/7758804), but requiring customized text for each tick of each subplot.
- Text labels work differently than numeric labels that are in the other example. Numeric labels match the tick position, but that is not the case for text labels.
- `.get_yticklabels()` gets `[Text(0, 0, 'Southampton'), Text(0, 1, 'Cherbourg'), Text(0, 2, 'Queenstown')]` for each subplot
- As shown below, extract the text and position, and the use `.set_yticklabels` to set the new text label
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

fg = sns.catplot(x="age", y="embark_town",
                hue="sex", row="class",
                data=titanic[titanic.embark_town.notnull()],
                orient="h", height=2, aspect=3, palette="Set3",
                kind="violin", dodge=True, cut=0, bw=.2)

for ax in fg.axes.flat:  # iterate through each subplot
    labels = ax.get_yticklabels()  # get the position and text for each subplot
    for label in labels:
        _, y = label.get_position()  # extract the y tick position
        txt = label.get_text()  # extract the text
        txt = f'({y + 1}) {txt}'  # update the text string
        label.set_text(txt)  # set the text
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels)  # update the yticklabels
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this and for the explanation. Really useful!